# passing arguments to function expr() in rlang and the !! operator

Tags: r, rlang

## Define an expression

```
> xy <- expr(x+y)
```

Use it to build a second expression ... and it works

```
> expr(a + !!xy)

a + (x + y)
```

simply changing the order of the arguments and it stops working

```
> expr(!!xy + a)
Error in (function (x)  : object 'a' not found
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is way to make it work. Change the way `!!xy` has been used in `expr` and it will work. i.e

```
expr((!!xy) + a)

#(x + y) + a
```

The reason is that priority of all arithmetic and comparison operators are higher than `!`. Hence arithmetic and comparison operators binds tightly than `!`. e.g.:

```
> expr(!!2 + 3)
[1] 5
> expr((!!2) + 3)
(2) + 3
```

The r-documentation for [`quasiquotation`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlang/versions/0.1.6/topics/quasiquotation) has clearly mentioned it as:

> ```
> # The !! operator is a handy syntactic shortcut for unquoting with
> # UQ().  However you need to be a bit careful with operator
> # precedence. All arithmetic and comparison operators bind more
> # tightly than `!`:
> quo(1 +  !! (1 + 2 + 3) + 10)
>
> # For this reason you should always wrap the unquoted expression
> # with parentheses when operators are involved:
> quo(1 + (!! 1 + 2 + 3) + 10)
>
> # Or you can use the explicit unquote function:
> quo(1 + UQ(1 + 2 + 3) + 10)
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replay
Have you any reference where all of this is explained?

Comment: @Andrea The reason is simple. The `!!` is shortcut of `UQ`. Operator precedence-wise `!!` is applied `after` arithmetic-operators. Hence it is advised to wrap the unquoted expression with parentheses.  I'm updating my answer with link of reference

Comment: @Andrea Have a look at updated answer. If it clarifies your query then  you can accept answer so that it will be helpful to future user.

Comment: Thanks @MRK your comments have been very usefull