# Unquoting the loop variable in `rlang::expr`

Tags: r, rlang, nse

I came across unexpected behavior when using operator `!!` to iteratively construct expressions that involve a loop variable.

Creating an expression from the loop variable itself, e.g.,

```
X <- list()
for( i in 1:3 )
  X[[i]] <- rlang::expr( !!i )
str(X)
# List of 3
#  $ : int 1
#  $ : int 2
#  $ : int 3
```

works as expected. However, attempting to construct any complex expression involving the loop variable, such as

```
Y <- list()
for( i in 1:3 )
    Y[[i]] <- rlang::expr( 1 + (!!i) )
str(Y)
# List of 3
#  $ : language 1 + 3L
#  $ : language 1 + 3L
#  $ : language 1 + 3L
```

seems to produce expressions that contain the final value of the loop variable. It's almost as if the expressions get captured as `quote( 1 + (!!i) )` during the loop, but the unquoting via `!!` happens only after the entire loop is executed, as opposed to at every iteration.

Can somebody please shed some light on this behavior? Is this a bug? The intended goal is to capture unevaluated expressions `1+1`, `1+2` and `1+3` with a loop. The expected output of `Y` would therefore be

```
# List of 3
#  $ : language 1 + 1L
#  $ : language 1 + 2L
#  $ : language 1 + 3L
```

Side note: the extra parentheses around `!!i` are there to address [the potential issue of operator precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099709/passing-arguments-to-function-expr-in-rlang-and-the-operator).

Using `rlang 0.2.1`.

Comment: `rlang::expr( !! (1 + i) )` works (if in need of a quick workaround). Adding `str(Y)` inside `for(...) {...}` reveals that all expressions are indeed evaluated for the last `i`.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Unfortunately, `expr( !!(1 + i) )` collapses the expression. The goal is to capture the unevaluated expressions `1+1`, `1+2`, `1+3`. Your suggestion of putting `str(Y)` inside `for(...) {...}` has me scratching my head even more. It looks as if the first expression is correctly captured as `1+1` in the first iteration, but then gets modified to `1+2` at the second iteration and finally becomes `1+3` by the time the loop finishes. However, further changes to `i` outside the loop have no effect. What gives?

Comment: This is called lazy evaluation. Check my answer for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `for` creates some sort of environment / frame where evaluation takes place at the end (for the last `i`). One possible way to deal with this is to avoid `for` and use `purrr::` or `lapply`.

```r
Y <- purrr::map(1:3, ~ rlang::expr( 1 + (!! .) )) 
str(Y)
#> List of 3
#>  $ : language 1 + 1L
#>  $ : language 1 + 2L
#>  $ : language 1 + 3L

Y <- lapply(1:3, function(i) rlang::expr( 1 + (!! i) )) 
str(Y)
#> List of 3
#>  $ : language 1 + 1L
#>  $ : language 1 + 2L
#>  $ : language 1 + 3L
```

`while` works in console but it fails when used with `reprex` (not shown).

```r
Y <- list()
i <- 1L
while (i <= 3) {
    Y[[i]] <- rlang::expr( 1 + (!!i) )
    i <- i + 1L
}
str(Y)
#> List of 3
#>  $ : language 1 + 1L
#>  $ : language 1 + 2L
#>  $ : language 1 + 3L
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understood you correctly. Are you perhaps after `rlang::eval_tidy` to evaluate the expression?

```
X <- list()
for( i in 1:3 )
    X[[i]] <- rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::expr(!!i + 1))
#[[1]]
#[1] 2
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 3
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 4
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Maurits. The intended goal is to capture unevaluated expressions `1 + 1`, `1 + 2`, and `1 + 3` using a loop. I updated the original question with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this is the case, but I think it has to do with lazy evaluation. The main idea is that R does not evaluate an expression when it is not used. In your example, `rlang::expr( !!i )` is "self-evaluating" because an expression that represents a constant is the constant itself. This causes the following to evaluate at every iteration of the for loop:

```
X <- list()
for( i in 1:3 )
  X[[i]] <- rlang::expr( !!i )
```

Notice that the elements of `X` are no longer expressions but integers:

```
> str(X)
List of 3
 $ : int 1
 $ : int 2
 $ : int 3

identical(rlang::expr(1),1)
# [1] TRUE
```

Your second example, however, has `rlang::expr( 1 + (!!i) )`, which remains an expression at each iteration of the for loop without evaluation. Lazy evaluation causes R to only evaluate `i` at the end of the loop, which takes the last value of `i`. The way to fix this issue is to `force` the evaluation of `i`:

```
Y <- list()
for( i in 1:3 ){
  force(i)
  Y[[i]] <- rlang::expr( 1 + (!!i) )
}

> str(Y)
List of 3
 $ : language 1 + 1L
 $ : language 1 + 2L
 $ : language 1 + 3L
```

Note that lazy evaluation used to also affect functions like `lapply` as discussed in this question: [Explain a lazy evaluation quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129902/explain-a-lazy-evaluation-quirk), but it has since been fixed in R 3.2.0. Higher order functions like `lapply` now forces the arguments to the inner function. See @jhin's answer in the same question. This is why @Mike Badescu's `lapply` solution now works.

Comment: Thanks for this, @avid_useR. Very insightful! I suspected that lazy evaluation was at play, but what gives me pause is @Mike Badescu's suggestion of doing `for( i in 1:3 ) { Y[[i]] <- rlang::expr( 1 + (!!i) ); str(Y) }` I would expect that `str(Y)` forces evaluation of `!!i` the same way `force(i)` does, but perhaps that's not the case? I suppose `str` simply displays the content of its argument, without necessary forcing its evaluation?

Comment: @ArtemSokolov What you really want is to force `i` to evaluate instead of `Y` (force the argument to a function instead of the function itself). If you do `str(Y)`, lazy evaluation still applies because `Y` is still being modified at each iteration. Try instead: `for( i in 1:3 ) {Y[[i]] <- rlang::expr( 1 + (!!i) ); str(i) }`. This forces evaluation of `i` at each iteration.